# Silverlight 4 & WCF Cannot insert data record with a long sting as a method param

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I'm working on a project using Silverlight 4 and WCF.  All of the web methods, exept one are working fine.  In Silverlight I use a custom xaml writer to write a string and I want to save the string in a database.  Using the Insert method on the web service, I can insert data as long as the string parameter is not too large.  When trying to insert the string created by the xaml writer, I get an error.  I used Fiddler to trace the error and I"m getting and HTTP 400 error.  I have read in numerous post that I need to change the config settings on the servce hosting in the web app and in the client config in the Silverlight app.  I have made all the changes that I could find on the web.  I don't know what else to try and I have ran out of resources.  When I paste the xaml string into Notepad and save it, the file is only 425 KB.  Here are the changes I've made to each config file.  Hopefully someone can pointout anyting I'm missing.  Thank you for looking over my issue.

web.config file in web app:

```
     <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <!-- Enable the serializer to serialize greater number of records -->
        <behavior name="CustomServiceBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
 <bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="CustomBinding">
     <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
      maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
   </basicHttpBinding>
```

ServiceReferences.ClientConfig:

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_DBService" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost.:49436/BuilderWebService/DBService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_DBService"
            contract="ServiceReference1.DBService" name="BasicHttpBinding_DBService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config in the binding tag you shoiuld add attributes: *maxBufferPoolSize, maxReceivedMessageSize, maxBufferSize*:

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="CustomBinding"
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
      </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

In my example, I've provided the maximal values for the sizes, but you can define the sizes you actually need. Hope it will help you.

Comment: I made the changes to my web.config file and I'm still getting the following error: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. I tested the web method with a small string and it worked fine. I still have a problem with the larger xaml string being passed to the method.

Comment: Try to add `maxStringContentLength="<required size>"` attribute to `readerQuotas` tag of bothe client and server configurations

Comment: Adding the maxStringContentLength attribute worked.  I check the database and everything is working correctly.  Thank you very much for your help!  I can now move forward, thanks to you.

Comment: I'm glad that it works. Can you please mark my response as the answer?